# Adding a timed delay after pressing a button to prevent button spam

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Say I have 4 buttons

```
    <button id="one">One</button>
    <button id="two">Two</button>
    <button id="three">Three</button>
    <button id="four">Four</button>
```

and to prevent spam, I want to make it so that whenever any of the buttons are pressed, none of them are able to be pressed again for the next 0.6 seconds.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: you should disable buttons on click and re - enable them on a certain timeout

use javascript setTimeout() function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) are some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this javascript code:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        disableButtons(true);
        setTimeout(function(){disableButtons(false);}, 600);
    });    
}
function disableButtons(state){
    for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
        btns[i].disabled = !!state;    
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to run this code after your page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a "click shield".

Here's how you can do it with jQuery.

```
var clickShield = false;
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (!clickShield) {
    clickShield = true;
    console.log('handle click event');
    setTimeout(function() {
      clickShield = false;
    }, 600);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do something like:

```
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
<button id="four">Four</button>

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    $("button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("button").removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 600);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Get button elements
var els = document.getElementByTagName('button');

// Add an event handler to click event
// that triggers settimeout to set the disable value
els.addListener('click', function(){
  setTimeout(els.disable, 600);
}, true);
```

*not tested*

Answer (score -1):

Like prasadmadanayake says in his comment you can do it by disable/enable the button.

Here is a working example:

```js
var intVal = 0;
$('button').on('click',function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function(){enable(id)}, 3000);
                               
    return true;
});

function enable (id) {
    $('#'+id).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button id="one">One</button>
    <button id="two">Two</button>
    <button id="three">Three</button>
    <button id="four">Four</button>
```